# Input with datalist calling twice

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vue and am trying to build a form with a `datalists`. The code I've written seems to work fine but I'm not sure why the dropdown list will appear twice. Once when nothing is typed into the input where it will show all the options available, and the second time when an option is chosen and the dropdown will show only the options that match the one typed. Is there a way to get rid of the second dropdown, where it will only show the dropdown once?

**Template**

```html
<input list=list1 v-model="test">
<datalist id=list1>
    <option v-for "item in items" :value="item" :key="item"></option>
</datalist>
```

**Script**

```js
export defaults{
    data(){
        items: [1,2,3,4,5],
        test: ''
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `{{ item }}` instead of binding `:value` to show and populate the value.

```html
<div>
    <input type="text" list="list1" v-model="test" @change="onChange()" />
    <datalist id="list1">
      <!-- use normal {{ item }} here without binding value-->
      <option v-for="item in items" :key="item">{{ item }}</option>
    </datalist>
</div>
```